# Attempting to import `reqwest::async` errors stating that `async` is a reserved keyword

Tags: syntax, rust, reqwest, rust-2018

I want to make asynchronous HTTP requests using the [`reqwest`](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) crate. I have the following code:

```
// see https://docs.rs/reqwest/*/reqwest/async/index.html
use reqwest::async::Client;
```

When I attempt to compile my code I get the following error:

```
error: expected identifier, found reserved keyword `async`
 --> src/main.rs:1:14
  |
1 | use reqwest::async::Client;
  |              ^^^^^ expected identifier, found reserved keyword
```

How do I import from the `async` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `reqwest::async` was created before `async` was a reserved keyword (which happened in Rust 2018, I believe) previously this Just Worked™.

Now that `async` is a reserved keyword you need to use the [raw identifier](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/raw-identifiers.html) syntax:

```rust
use request::r#async::Client;
```

Comment: You can also "fix" this by not opting in to Edition 2018 in your `Cargo.toml`. 2015 is the default and `asyn` is not reserved there.